# one address have two values?

Tags: c, pointers

The following code shows me that for one address I have two values. For an example:

```
Address is: 0xbfcca1ac <br>
Value is: 5

Address is: 0xbfcca1ac <br>
Value is: -1077108308
```

What am i doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Input(int *A, int n) {

int i, x=5;

for(i=0; i<n*n; i++) {
   *(A+i) = x;
}

printf("\n\n\n\nAddress is: %p\n", A);
printf("Value is: %d\n", *A);

}

main() {

int A[3][3], i, j, n=3;

Input(A, n);

printf("\nAddress is: %p\n", A);
printf("Value is: %d", *A);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're passing incompatible pointer types, so your dereferences are inconsistent.  Your compiler should have given you several warnings.  Fix those warnings before expecting meaningful results.  Just remember that `int [3][3]` and `int *` are never compatible.

Comment: You cannot convert ‘int (*)[3]’ to ‘int*, The output will be inconsistent.

Comment: This is where compiling with *Warnings Enabled* (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`) and not accepting code that compiles with warnings will solve problems like this for you.

Comment: Your program has completely undefined behaviour, so you cannot infer anything from its output

Comment: You probably want to print `A[0][0]` in main.  `A[0]` decays to a pointer, and `%d` is the wrong format specifier for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `main()`, `A` is a 2D array, so `*A` is an array of 3 integers.     Printing `*A` using the `%d` format gives undefined behaviour, since `*A` is not an int.

In your `Input()`, `A` is a pointer to an `int`, so its value is treated as the address of an`int`.  `*A` is then the value of an `int`, which is assumed to be at that address.

The value that `main()` passes to `Input()` will the address of `A[0]`.   That has type "pointer to array of 3 int", but will happen to have the value equal to (in `main()`) `&A[0][0]`.

Compilers will (if configured right) give warnings about your code, since it is passing values to functions of different types that those functions will expect.    Since there is (at minimum) potential for undefined behaviour due to mismatch of types (function expecting a parameter of one type, but being given another), you should really not ignore such warnings.   Even if you are somehow able to reason through what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int int_of_three[3];
//Another way of saying int_of_three is int[3]

void Input(int_of_three A[3], int n) //int_of_three *A should also be fine
                                     //provided you play by the limits.
  {

     int i, x=5;
        for(i=0; i<n*n; i++) 
        {
         *(*(A+i)) = x;
        }

          printf("\n\n\n\nAddress is: %p\n", *A);
          // *A decays to another pointer.
          printf("Value is: %d\n", **A);
          printf("\nAddress is: %p\n", *(A+1));
          printf("Value is: %d", *(*(A+1)));


   }

main() 
{

int_of_three A[3];
int n=3;
    Input(A, n);
    printf("\nAddress is: %p\n", *A);
    printf("Value is: %d", **A);
    printf("\nAddress is: %p\n", *(A+1));
    printf("Value is: %d", *(*(A+1)));

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just make an error in the `main` when printing the value. Since `A` is a pointer to a pointer to int you should have: `printf("Value is: %d",**A);` (double dereference).

You compiler should have warned you for incompatible types when passing arguments, a cast will make your compiler silent: `Input((int *)A,n);`.

Also use the right prototype for `main`...